# How to describe a situation in written

Tags: phrase-request

My friend was hit by a car as a pedestrian. At the moment, she is in hospital and is given little chance to live. How could I describe her current condition?

Comment: Medical staff would often say her condition is ***critical***, but ordinary people might more likely say it's ***serious*** (though somewhat curiously, the latter is usually considered *less serious than "critical"* by the healthcare professionals).

Comment: I think using "she is given little chance to live" is sufficient to describe the situation. There are others, depending on the actual condition: critical (some hope for survival), grave (basically no hope for survival), "on life support", among others.

Comment: UK media are much given to talking about *life-threatening* or, in lesser cases, *life-changing*. https://www.accinet.co.uk/life-changing-injuries/

Answer (score 2):

Medical staff would often say **her condition is critical**, but ordinary people might more likely say it's serious (though somewhat curiously, the latter is usually considered less serious than "critical" by the healthcare professionals). – FumbleFingers